# FS register access violation on Windows 7

Tags: assembly, windows-7, crash, windows-xp, access-violation

Crashing instructions (any one of these will cause an access violation):

```
LODS BYTE PTR FS:[ESI]
LODS WORD PTR FS:[ESI]
LODS DWORD PTR FS:[ESI]
```

I am trying to fix a crash for a client trying to port a Windows 95 game but as there is no source code available, I am currently debugging in assembly. The application frequently and randomly crashes on Windows 7 but works fine on Windows XP. Debugging it indicates an Access Violation and it occurs when trying to access the FS register.

I have debugged and compared on both XP and Windows 7 and found that the access violation occurs because when accessing the FS register using ESI, the address is always out of range on Windows 7. I also tried adding an SEH exception handler to the assembly code but the access violation happens even when reading FS:[0] (the data there is shown as unknown):

```
PUSHAD
PUSH 004DE918
MOV EAX,DWORD PTR FS:[0]
PUSH EAX
```

Could the application be causing a register corruption but what could be the likely cause of this happening only on Windows 7 but not on XP? Does the different FS register selector of 53 on Windows 7 have anything to do with this? Any suggestions or solutions for me to try?

Thank you!

Comment: How about simply running the app in WinXP compatibility mode? Or in XP Mode (XP VM in Win7)?

Comment: i tried that and the other compatibility settings as well but the crashing still occurs..

Comment: Even the XP VM known as XP Mode?

Comment: the VM works but that is not the solution... the game works in XP and I need to get it working on Windows 7 without crashing, I have been trying to step-through the code in assembly to try and fix the problem but with my limited knowledge, I am unable to figure out why ESI ends up with an invalid address...

Comment: The program apparently has a bug dependent on OS behavior. It could just as well be an uninitialized variable, use of a bad pointer/index/size, use of memory after it's been freed, memory corruption, failure to check some error code, an interesting race condition, etc. One thing that may be useful is running this app under `app verifier` + `windbg` in Windows XP and seeing what settings in the app verifier (if any) cause the program to crash even in Windows XP. You can probably do the same under Windows 7, but the search for what makes the game to stop crashing may be longer or even fruitless.

Comment: hmm.. i did already try app verifier on both xp and windows 7, it does not crash on XP and there are no problems but on windows 7 i get warnings about "Used a Windows System directory path that was not obtained using an approved method.".. and another problem is that I cannot get the game to run with WinDbg due to an assertion error that prevents the game from executing. I can only run it with OllyDbg and IDA Pro..

Comment: You should probably disable `first-chance exceptions` in WinDbg. Also, you should really play with memory allocations in AV, how they are made (see special pool, pool tracking).

Comment: Perhaps you could edit it out (in the disassembly)?

Comment: You mentioned "memory allocations in AV", what is AV?

Answer (score 0):

FS register is used by Windows for quick access to the TIB (Thread Information Block) that is also called TEB (Thread Environment Block). FS store selector of the segment that is cover TIB data structure in memory. I expect that this segment have very small size and due to this access on any address out of the TEB size will lead to the General Fault exception. In fact, TEB data structure layout and storing of the address of the TEB in the FS is undocumented and can be changed by Microsoft from version to version. Maybe the TEB size was reduced in Windows 7.

In any case to discuss the issue more productively, please, provide the value of FS and ESI on the crash moment.

Comment: The value at FS when it crashes is always ????? on OllyDbg and it says Access Violation when reading [FFFFFFFF]... as for ESI, the address is always changing but mostly out of the range of my data segment (I will need to debug again to check the values), sometimes it is within the range of my data segment but the instruction it points to is invalid

Comment: Try to use windbg to get values of FS and ESI. It is important to know this values to understand which from it is wrong.